Error in Building Vue + Electron Desktop App
I am trying to build a Vue + Electron desktop app. While the app works properly when I run npm run electron:serve, I am encountering errors during the build process with the following commands:

npm run build
npm run electron:build

Error Details:
I get the following error message:
Error in ./node_modules/vuex/dist/vuex.esm-bundler.js + 5 modules  

Unexpected end of JSON input  

ERROR: Vue CLI build failed. Please resolve any issues with your build and try again.  

Steps I Tried:

Uninstalled and reinstalled npm and vuex packages.
Verified the setup multiple times.

Despite these attempts, the issue persists.

Try firing npm run electron:build -- --verbose this will give you detailed errors.
